# Google Spreadsheets - Join or Concatenate text from multiple rows that have matching values in one of the columns

Tags: google-sheets, formula

As the title says, I need to join or concatenate text from multiple rows that have matching values in one of the columns. (Using latest Firefox, Widows 7).

In Sheet1 I have a table that looks like this (sorry if it looks messy - I don't know how to do a neat table on SO):

David | 1 | Blue 
Steve | 1 | Green
James | 2 | 
Chris | 1 | 
Steve | 3 | Blue
Jack |  1 | 
Ben |   1 | 
James | 1 | 
Jack   | 2 |    Yellow
George |    4   |

In Sheet2, I would like a table that looks like this:

David   |1| Blue
Steve   |4| Green & Blue
James   |3|  
Chris   |1|  
Jack    |3| Yellow
Ben |1|  
George  |4|

Column A show unique values (names) and column B shows the sum for that name.

I have successfully generated columns A and B but I'm having difficulty generating the third column which should return 'Green & Blue' for Steve and 'Yellow' for Jack etc.

Does anyone know how to do this? Your help would be much appreciated.

I have generated Sheet2 columns A and B with the follwing formulas:
Column A: =UNIQUE(Sheet1!A:A) 
Column B: =SUMIF(Sheet1!A:A,A1,Sheet1!B:B).

Here is the spreadsheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0Avg34WusBUlRdGY1X3BSRlYxaWVkSmo3eVQzYlNvMXc

Thanks for looking.

Answer (score 2):

Use the JOIN function combined with the FILTER function
So in Column C:

```
=JOIN(" & ",filter(Sheet1!C:C,Sheet1!A:A=A1))
```

Hope it helps.