# Need Header's In Remarks With Count and Concatenate

Tags: excel, excel-formula, count

Need a help for below function. I have Two tables below T1 is which is data available and T2 is what data i want from T1.

I need answer like in T2 table though formula.

For `Count()` and Remarks self can arrive based on using below function, But need to help for getting the Dates In the Remark.

Function Currently Tired

```
=COUNTIF(C6:F6,I5)&" Days Absent On "
```

Need Exact Formula to Arrive Dates as well in remarks like below snap.

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately unless you run Exel D365 or 2019 version, [this is not easily possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46542051/concatenate-multiple-matches-in-excel).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `TEXTJOIN` function is not available, you may try:

> =IF(COUNTIF(C6:F6,$I$5)=0, NA()
>   , COUNTIF(C6:F6,$I$5) & " days absent on " & 
>   LEFT(CONCATENATE(IF(C6=$I$5,$C$5&",",""),IF(D6=$I$5,$D$5&",",""),IF(E6=$I$5,$E$5&",",""),IF(F6=$I$5,$F$5&",","")),
>   LEN(CONCATENATE(IF(C6=$I$5,$C$5&",",""),IF(D6=$I$5,$D$5&",",""),IF(E6=$I$5,$E$5&",",""),IF(F6=$I$5,$F$5&",","")))-1)
>   )

[image]

Comment: Great ! Thanks For It !

Answer (score 1):

This will work only on Excel D365 and 2019 versions which utilizes `TextJoin` function.

> =IF(COUNTIF(B6:E6,"A")>0, COUNTIF(B6:E6,"A") & " Day(s) Absent on " & TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,IF(B6:E6="A",$B$1:$E$1,"")), "NA")

This is entered as *array formula* by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>

**Illustration:**
[image]

Comment: Great ! Thanks For It !